# WordPress URL conflict with sitemap.xml

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress page with `post_name` as sitemap. I also have a `sitemap.xml` file. The problem is when I load the `www.mysite.com/sitemap` it loads the XML sitemap, not the post. `www.mysite.com/sitemap/` (note the trailing slash) returns 404. I renamed the `sitemap.xml`, then `www.mysite.com/sitemap/` loads the post and `www.mysite.com/sitemap` redirects to `www.mysite.com/sitemap/`. Can anybody tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to install Yoast SEO Plugin to generate xml sitemap, Yoast SEO url is normally www.mysite.com/sitemap_index.xml

and deactivate Google xml sitemap. (hopefully your are using it)